# element.tagName is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-validate

For the following code, element.tagName is undefined.

```
$('#page1').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    $('form').validate({

       errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
           console.log(element.tagName);

           if (element.tagName === "input") {
              error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
           } else {
              error.insertAfter(element);
           }
       }
   });
});
```

This works however:

```
if (element.attr("type") === “text”) {
```

I want to set `error.insertAfter($(element).parent())` on all inputs. Why is tagName not working?

Comment: How do you invoke `errorPlacement()`? You're not mixing jQuery and DOM objects here?

Comment: Use uppercase `"INPUT"` in your test. Or if infact Teemu is right and you're mixing jQuery and DOM objects. use this - `if(element.is('input'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check for input, like:

```
if( element.is('input') ) {
  //its input
}
```

or get base element from jQuery object, like:

```
if (element[0].tagName === "INPUT") {
   //its input
}
```